# how to get results with zero values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

my query is

```
select m.year_id,Count(*) as Distinctions from NewTestDB.dbo.[Master_MARKS2005] as m
join NewTestDB.dbo.Master_Student as s
on s.Student_id=m.Student_Id
join NewTestDB.dbo.Master_School as sc
on sc.school_id=s.school_code
where sc.SCHOOL_CODE= 'an0001' and m.YEAR_ID between 1 and 8 and m.[NRC_CLASS]='D'
group by m.year_id,
```

i want out of all year_id's between 1 to 8 but now i am getting only when m.[NRC_CLASS]='D'
how to rewrite this query so that i can get count as '0' when no rows in the m.NRC_CLASS column contains 'D' value

Comment: Was that `group by m.year_id,` with comma at the end typo or is there another column that you use for grouping?

Comment: I understand its a silly question but i didn't it at that moment.Thank you all for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Left Join to achieve this

Like you can try this

```
SELECT m.year_id,COUNT(*) AS Distinctions 
       FROM NewTestDB.dbo.[Master_MARKS2005] AS m
LEFT JOIN 
       NewTestDB.dbo.Master_Student AS s
ON 
       s.Student_id=m.Student_Id
JOIN 
       NewTestDB.dbo.Master_School AS sc
ON 
       sc.school_id=s.school_code
WHERE 
       sc.SCHOOL_CODE= 'an0001' 
       AND 
       m.YEAR_ID BETWEEN 1 AND 8 
       AND 
       m.[NRC_CLASS]='D' 
GROUP BY m.year_id,
```

Comment: thank you very much and really sorry for taking your time for simple things.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select  m.year_id,
        Count(CASE WHEN m.[NRC_CLASS]='D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Distinctions
from    NewTestDB.dbo.[Master_MARKS2005] as m
join    NewTestDB.dbo.Master_Student as s
on      s.Student_id=m.Student_Id
join    NewTestDB.dbo.Master_School as sc
on      sc.school_id=s.school_code
where   sc.SCHOOL_CODE= 'an0001' and m.YEAR_ID between 1 and 8
group   by m.year_id,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select isnull(m.year_id,''),Count(*) as Distinctions from NewTestDB.dbo.[Master_MARKS2005] as m
left join NewTestDB.dbo.Master_Student as s
on s.Student_id=m.Student_Id
left join NewTestDB.dbo.Master_School as sc
on sc.school_id=s.school_code
where sc.SCHOOL_CODE= 'an0001' and m.YEAR_ID between 1 and 8 and m.[NRC_CLASS]='D'
group by m.year_id
```